# Want to pass an argument to my shell function

Tags: bash, shell

I am so frustrated with bash/shell functions.

I have this command:

```
grep -r '^struct task_struct ' include
```

And I want to add a function or an alias to my bashrc that lets me say something like

```
grepdefined "struct task_struct"
```

and have it run the command from above. And then another time I could run it with "struct task_info" or something. So frustrating.

I have this right now as I test everything and throw guesses at the problem:

```
function grepdefined() {
    test="$@";
    echo $test;
    grep -rni '^'$test' ' include;
    #echo "grep -rni'^'$test' ' include;"
}
```

It's only searching on the first word, "struct" in the "struct task_struct" that I'm passing in with grepdefined "struct task_struct".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your grep line like this:

```
grep -rni "^$test"  include
```

**Update**:

```
grep -rni "^$test"  include
```

actually becomes:

```
grep -rni "^struct task_struct"  include
```

However,

```
grep -rni '^'$test' ' include
```

gets interpreted as:

```
grep -rni ^struct task_struct include
```

If you notice above, the search pattern for grep is only `^struct`, whereas `task_struct` is considered as one of the files to search for the pattern along with `include` and hence the issue you faced where it was considering only `struct` not the whole thing. Its mandatory to double quote whenever its a multi-worded string.

Comment: Many thanks. Can you tell me why this works? I know it has to be something with escaping strings and what not, but I'm far from understanding it.

Comment: @cdietschrun : Updated the solution with more comments